# applying email patch with git

Tags: git, email, patch

I would like to apply a patch sent with git-send-email.

Currently I have to type everything to the specific files.This is a hacky and very slow as my workload is increasing.I would like to know how I could get a fairly large patch into my git tree faster for testing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks! My exact problem was how to save the patches into a .patch file ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check to see if the patch applies without errors:

```
git apply --check <patchname>
```

Apply the patch:

```
git apply <patch name>
```

[Here](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/12/git-tip-of-week-patches-by-email.html) is a blog post where you can get more info on email patches.

Comment: The patch is the body of the message.Do I copy and paste this as a diff file?

Comment: If the code is in the body of the email message take a look at [`git am`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-am)

Comment: @Aslaville: please select an answer if the issue is resolved. You have 13 questions without any selected answer.

Answer (score 12):

You can apply patches from email-formatted patch using any raw data viewer.

For example, GMail, in the current interface, has support for it.
You can apply a patch as a commit from a mail message following these steps:

1. Open the GMail web page in the message with patch data
2. Click at the ellipsis icon located at top-right of this message
3. Click at "Show Original". A new tab will open with the content of the message.
4. Click at "Copy to clipboard"
5. Open a terminal and change current directory to git-based root project directory
6. Certify that the working copy is clean
7. Run `git am`
8. Paste the code
9. Type `Ctrl-D` to finish the insertion

---

For more information, check:

[Kernel Newbies - Applying a patch tutorial](https://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/HowToApplyAPatch)

[Eletric Toolbox - Gmail view raw message article](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/gmail-view-raw-email-message/)