# My mailbox was received. But I don't know how to get the patch in the mailbox, because the content of the mailbox is only text

Tags: github

After I generated the patch, $ git send-email --to a1105773737@gmail.com ~/patches/*.patch sent the patch. My mailbox was received. But I don't know how to get the patch in the mailbox, because the content of the mailbox is only text.

Please take a look at the picture, I open the mailbox, I can only see a bunch of text, how should I merge the mailbox patch?

[image]

I feel the need to send the patch file to the mailbox, and then download the patch file, but I don't know how to send the file to the mailbox.

Comment: This problem has plagued me for a day. A French master answered me, but I still haven't solved the actual problem. I am sorry to continue asking him.

Comment: Is it that I understand that there is a problem? Can everyone help me? thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I open the mailbox, I can only see a bunch of text,

That is expected: those patches follow a [diff format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33718750/6309).

To apply those patch, save then content of the email and use [`git apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply).
Or, as [recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51995810/6309), copy paste the content of the email into [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) interractive step.

Comment: I am very touched, I am very excited, I am very grateful to you, I used git am to successfully merge the mail patch, I have been successful before, I did not understand the meaning of the patch mail, I always thought that you need to download the patch, then copy Go to the git library. I understand the deviation, so I have not understood git am correctly. Thank you for your patience, thank you French, I love you.